# GDB tui inside TMUX

Tags: gdb, tmux

I'm having trouble using gdb --tui mode inside tmux. The code display becomes garbled after stepping through the code. I'm using gdb 7.6.1 with tmux 1.6. I've also tried tmux 1.9a, and still experience this issue. gdb in tui mode works fine outside of tmux.

```
OS: CentOS release 6.4
Terminal emulator: terminator
TERM=xterm-256color
```

Thanks!

Actually, I just solved this. I changed TERM to screen-256color and it works. Thanks!

Comment: What are your OS, terminal emulator program and TERM environment variable?

Comment: OS: CentOS release 6.4, Terminal emulator: terminator, TERM=xterm-256color

Comment: Can you add screenshot of "grabled" display?

Comment: stackoverflow won't let me post images yet.. when stepping through code, and the source file changes, it displays the new file on top of the previous file.